# 'md5sum' and pipe doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, pipe

hi just copied this line of codes from the book :"think python" (I edited the filename from 'book.tex' to 'words.txt'

```
import os
filename = 'words.txt'
cmd = ' md5sum ' + filename
fp = os.popen(cmd)
res = fp.read()
stat = fp.close()
```

In the book:

```
>>> print res
1e0033f0ed0656636de0d75144ba32e0 book.tex
>>> print stat
None
```

but for me:

```
>>> print res

>>> print stat
1
```

why this happen(print a balnk line for print res and 1 for print stat)

Comment: It works for me; are you sure you have a `md5sum` command and that `words.txt` exists?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: `fp.close()` doesn't return the exit code though.

Comment: Works for me, are you sure the text file is really there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters assumed it does, reading now

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I can never make `stat` equal to `1`.

Comment: yes i have words.txt

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: my python version is 2.7.8

Comment: yes i'm using windows.

Comment: @anyname: right, `md5sum` is not available on Windows.

Comment: @anyname: and since on Windows `os.popen()` returns a different object, we can presume that it was that object whose `close()` method returned `1` here. I have no Windows machine at hand to test at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't come with a `md5sum` command. You can find similar utilities from the internet. Something like this might do: http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/

Answer (score 0):

os.open is deprecated (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen). It's recommended you switch to subprocess, ie:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['md5sum', 'words.txt'])
1e0033f0ed0656636de0d75144ba32e0 book.tex
```

Comment: The OP is following a specific book, and this answer doesn't address why the OP is seeing different output from everyone else.

Comment: Perhaps...but it's deprecated. Better to get used to the new way, rather than spinning wheels on the old (after which he may even discover why it was deprecated in the first place).